# When does $x_k$ converge if we know that $f(x_k)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a twice continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{k}) = 0$ for some series $(x_k)_k$.

Are there any conditions on $f$ (like unicity of a root, lipschitz continuity of the gradient, positive definiteness of jacobian matrix,...) that imply existence of the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_{k}$.

For instance, suppose $x^*$ is the unique solution of $f(x)=0$, do we know $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_{k} = x^{*}$?

Comment: Root unicity is not enough. Consider $f(x) = x e^{-x}$ and $x_k =k$. Root unicity AND limit of $f(x)$ not being $0$ whenever $|x| \to \infty$ is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we have to have an unique root, for if $a$ and $b$ are distinct roots the sequence $x_n$ equal to $a$ for odd $n$ and $b$ otherwise does not converge.
Second, we must have $f(\pm\infty)\neq 0$, because we want the sequence $x_n$ to be bound.
If we have both, then we shall obtain what you want:
The sequence $x_n$ will be bound, thus will have an accumulation point, let's say $x=\lim x_{k_n}$. As we have $f(x)=\lim f(x_{k_n})=0$, by continuity, we conclude that $x=x*$. Thus we conclude that the accumulations points of the sequence are unique. As the sequence is bounded and has only one accumulation point it must converge to it.

Comment: You claim "As the sequence is bounded and has only one accumulation point it must converge to it.". I don't think this holds in general. Can you give some more details please?

Comment: If a sequence is bounded and has only one accumulation point then it must converge to it: take any open neighborhood of this point. The number of elements of the sequence outside this neighborhood must be finite, otherwise it would have a sub sequence in a compact set, which would have another accumulation point outside the neighborhood

Comment: Yes, thanks. :)

Comment: @Arararararagi-kun So if I understand correctly, for the multivariate case the condition $f(\pm\infty) \neq 0$ just has to be replaced with $\lim_{\|x\| \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \neq 0$ to make sure the sequence is bounded? The rest of the argument will just stay the same.

Comment: Actually we must have a little stronger hypothesis, even in the dimension 1 case. We could have a sequence such that its image converge to zero without the function converge to zero. We must ensure that 0 is not an accumulation point of the image of any sequence that goes to infinite.